# how to use a Text component in javascript?

Tags: block-editor

I'm building an InspectorTools interface for a Gutenberg block. I can't figure out how to use the **Text** component. There aren't really any examples for use in javascript.
The page https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/text/ it gives this example:

```js
import {Text} from '@wordpress/components';

const HeroPanel = () => (
    <>
        <Text variant="title.large" as="h1">Hello World!</Text>
        <Text variant="body">Greetings to you!</Text>
    </>
);
```

I have tried in a number of ways but I always [get this error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=)  :

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Here are a few of my attempts:

```js
createElement(PanelRow, {}, createElement(Text, { variant: 'title.small', as: 'h3' }, __('This is a test', 'my-textdomain')) )

createElement(PanelRow, {}, createElement(Text, { as: 'h3' }, __('This is a test', 'my-textdomain')) )

createElement(PanelRow, {}, createElement(Text, { variant: 'title.small' }, __('This is a test', 'my-textdomain')) )

createElement(PanelRow, {}, createElement(Text, __('This is a test', 'my-textdomain')) )

createElement(PanelRow, {}, createElement(Text, {}, __('This is a test', 'my-textdomain')) )

createElement(PanelRow, {}, createElement(Text, { label: __('This is a test', 'my-textdomain')}) )
```

None of my attempts have worked, they all give the same error.
What would be the correct way to use a simple **Text** component?
My objective in this case is to create a label for a **ButtonGroup** component which, as far as I can tell, doesn't have a **label** property (I have only found an **accessibilityLabel** property which is created on the ButtonGroup but which is not however visible on the interface, obviously).

Comment: React requires you to use either tag or component names in `<>` tags, they can't be empty. The error is because you are wrapping the text in an empty `<>` `</>` element - you can use a `<Fragment></Fragment>` or a `<div></div>` to resolve that issue.

Comment: I am extracting **Text** as a constant from the **wp.components** library, shouldn't that already handle the html markup? Just as I am extracting **Button**, **ButtonGroup**, **SelectControl**, **ToggleControl**... All of these handle the markup on their own:
```javascript
(function (components) {
 const { PanelBody, PanelRow, Button, ButtonGroup, BaseControl, Text } = components; 
}( wp.components ));
```
Then in my **edit(props)**:
```javascript
return createElement('div', {}, [
 createElement(PanelRow, {}, createElement(ToggleControl, { label: 'My toggle control', }) )
])
```

Comment: (In any case I did resolve the problem of creating a **label** for the **ButtonGroup**, I found the **BaseControl** component and I made the **ButtonGroup** a child of the **BaseControl** which can have **label** and **help** properties and applies them to the child **ButtonGroup** component.)

Comment: Yes, components handle their own markup - but you can't place them inside of an empty `<>` tag.

Comment: It seems to me quite counterintuitive to talk about a **Text component** which needs to be wrapped in another tag. I could just as easily create a **span** tag on my own. If **Text** is considered a component it should take care of it's own markup or create it's own React tags, in my opinion, otherwise what's the use of calling it a "component"? Are you saying that in order to use the **Text component** it would need to be wrapped in say a **Fragment**?

Comment: Yes. That's a limitation of React - having to return a single container element. The `<Fragment>` is specifically for cases like yours - it does not render an actual HTML tag, but it serves as the required wrapper.

Comment: If you were returning just one `<Text>` component you wouldn't need a wrapper, but because you're returning two, that's where the need for a `<Fragment>` or other wrapper comes in.